# Naming a table that is already a reserved word

Tags: sql-server

I've found that coming up with short, meaningful names that don't conflict with reserved words is one of the most challenging parts of programming. In sql server, you can always wrap table names in square brackets, like [order], but that looks too ugly.

Examples are:

- order for customer orders. I might called it OH for orderHeader.
- cast might be a good name for a table of cast members. I might call it the person table.
- user would be a good table name to have. I might call it usr instead.
- convert might be a good table name for some kind of conversion.

Q: Do you have a certain trick or technique that you use when you can't think of another name for a table?

I thought about just adding an underscore to the end of the table name if I really wanted to use it, like order_, cast_, user_, convert_.

Comment: You're right - it's always a challenge, and I try to avoid the [] "hack", too...makes the code far less clear. The thing I typically do is jump onto an online thesaurus and find a similar, useful word.

Comment: Does your `order` table only contain a single order? Ditto for `user`? There's an obvious way to change those names to something that better represents the whole table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes - I always prefer plural names for tables...and that clashes far less often. And...`select stuff from orders where...` reads better

Comment: I would definitely avoid abbreviations. Things like OH are just awful. If it stands for OrderHeader why not call the table OrderHeader isntead a cryptic replacement. It is easy to remember when it is currently fresh but somebody new is going to want to kill you if they inherit a database with 50 tables with names like OH, JP. KD, TR. And for something like a conversion why not name it Conversion(s)? Naming is certainly challenging but don't overthink (or over simplify) it.

Comment: I used to hate escaping names, with square brackets.  But I no longer feel the same.  There are two reasons for my change of heart.  #1: If `Order` is the best name, then use it.  #2. Writing SQL takes time.  You can boost your productivity using query designers if you can learn to live with ugly code (there are [add-ins](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx) that can fix this).